# Book Suggestion (Calculus) for undergraduate level

Tags: calculus, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am starting my first year of undergraduate degree soon enough and the first course on mathematics would be Calculus 1. So, I am asking for some suggestions on the books I should use.

I already have fair bit of understanding about calculus from highschool/intermediate corses but not very rigorous.

Also, I am more concerned with self study

I am getting suggestions for Spivak and apostol (single variable) mainly, However if there are some other better texts then I would also look up to them. So which one should I prefer?

Comment: I like to reccomend [this](https://www.amazon.in/Multivariable-Calculus-Analysis-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1493970844/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&qid=1609578830&refinements=p_27%3ASudhir+R.+Ghorpade&s=books&sr=1-1) and [this](https://www.amazon.in/Course-Calculus-Real-Analysis/dp/8181284852/ref=tmm_pap_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1609578878&sr=1-2)

Comment: Thanks, I am also considering limaye and ghorpade. Can you please tell if you have read spivak also, what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Spivak is superior to almost everything imo.

Comment: For self study the books I mentioned are good and it also gives enough rigor